# Получение значений объединенных ячеек из файла Excel (C#)

Tags: c#

Всем привет! 
Эта проблема меня мучает уже не один день. Прогу пишу на C#. В программу загружается экселевский файл с таблицей бухгалтерских проводок (рисунок во вложении). Я создаю строковый массив значений этой таблицы. Загвоздка в том, что, например, при обработке счета 08 в массив будет добавлено три значения. Перовое будет 08 и два пустых, так как объединены три ячейки в одну. 
Уважаемые знатоки, вопрос! Как сделать, чтобы из объединенной ячейки в массив добавлять только первое значение, игнорируя остальные пустые?

Я использую библиотеку Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. С помощью rng.MergeCells проверяю на объединение ячеек, если нет объединения, то просто вывожу значение ячейки, а, если есть, то в бой идет rng.MergeArea. Но это нихрена не работает, потому что массив получается пустым

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
введите сюда код
```

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас код не работает, то покажите его в вопросе.

А в принципе здесь нет ничего сложного:

```
    private dynamic getValue(Range rng)
    {
        if (rng.MergeCells) {
            return rng.MergeArea.Cells[1,1].Value;
        } else {
            return rng.Value;
        }
    }
```